# Swift: Function-argument with "for"

Tags: ios, swift

I have seen this function-override:

```
override func prepare(for seque: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        ...
}
```

What the actual function does is clear to me. What confuses me currently is this "for" in front of the argument-label. Within the function only the argument-label ("seque") is used.

**What's the purpose of the "for"?**

It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: `for` is an argument label. Here is a ref: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html look for `Argument Labels` on a page for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` is an argument label.

> Each function parameter has both an *argument label* and a *parameter name*. The argument label is used when calling the function; each argument is written in the function call with its argument label before it.

Argument labels can help with readability by allowing you to use a label that makes sense when calling a function and a different parameter name in the function body.

Consider the function in your question. The caller writes

```
someVC.prepare(for: someSegue, sender:sender)
```

This reads somewhat like a sentence "prepare for some segue".

In the implementation of the function you can use the more meaningful `segue` rather than the less meaningful `for`.

Comment: Ah, I think I've got it now: It's for having a more descriptive name when invoking the function. For example: func add(first a: Int, second b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

print(add(first: 9, second: 5))

Comment: Within the function I use the shorter ones (a and b).

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Answer (score 2):

While you are declaring a func. you can set labels to arguments.

The argument labels will not be used in func.

When you're creating a function like..

```
func setBorderTo(view: UIView) { ...  }
```

You call the above func. like this...

```
 setBorderTo(view: <Your View>) //here "view" used inside the func.
```

and when you declared a func. like this...

```
func setBorderTo(_ view: UIView) { ... } //here inside you can access view
```

then you should call func. like this...

```
setBorderTo(<Your View>)
```

So calling func. like `setBorderTo(view)` make more sense than `setBorderTo(view: <Your View>)` b'coz here you do not need to write `view` label here.

**EDIT:**

The use of argument labels can allow a function to be called in an expressive, sentence-like manner, while still providing a function body that is readable and clear in intent.

But ultimately its depend on you. You can use argument labels or you can commit it too using underscore "_" at the start of the func. parameters.

Comment: Well, yes. But in my example above "seque" is the label. But what is this "for" in front of it? Respectively: What's the purpose of "for"?

Comment: Please see edit.